# Existe um grupo específico de usuários de Mathematica.SE em português?

Tags: debate

Primeiramente me perdoem se estou fazendo esta pergunta neste canal, porque sei que aqui deve ser perguntado assuntos referentes a programação.

Enfim, sou um usuário iniciante, mas com muitas perguntas na comunidade Mathematica.SE (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com)

Consigo várias respostas e com qualidade. Mas como é uma comunidade mundial tenho que perguntar em inglês. Mas infelizmente tenho um pouco de dificuldade.

É comum obter informações nesta comunidade sobre este software?

Comment: Já tentaram criar um grupo de matemática em português aqui no StackOverflow/StackExchange por meio do caminho oficial para isso (Area 51). Entretanto, não deu certo, pois a StackOverflow/StackExchange ainda não aceita comunidades em línguas que não seja o inglês exceto para versões localizadas do StackOverflow.

Comment: **Nota para futuros leitores**, sempre que quiser saber se existe um site especifico pesquise em: http://stackexchange.com/sites#users ou acompanhe os feeds: http://stackexchange.com/feeds/sites

Answer (score 4):

O local não é dos mais adequados, normalmente seria melhor perguntar no que costumamos chamar de [metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (de toda a rede). Mas como não temos outro canal em português, dá para responder aqui.

Não existe ainda. É possível tentar criar uma proposta no [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Mas no momento a SO Inc., dona da rede Stack Exchange, não tem condições de criar um novo site em português e é pouco provável ocorra tão cedo, mesmo que o site se mostre viável pelo processo do Area 51, o que não é tão fácil acontecer.

Acho mais provável que tenha que continuar na versão em inglês.